# Windows 7, Drivers, Cloning and Sysprep

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, clone, sysprep

<s>I have Windows 7 working on one machine but when I move it off to the new machine it crashes. If this is a driver issue do I need to download the drivers and install them first? Or do I install Windows 7 on the new machine first then copy the drivers folder over to the other disk so it will boot up correctly?</s>

EDIT: I was trying this as well:
http://www.todo-backup.com/support/tutorial/redeploy-system-to-dissimilar-hardware.htm

EDIT: I tried sysprep but on bootup I see the Windows logo then the system crashes. I can stick the drive back in the old hardware and it runs fine.

Comment: Which driver is causing the crash?

Comment: Not sure. I did pull PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396 and PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397 from an error log.

Comment: are you just trying to move a HDD or are you actually capturing an image?

Comment: Ideally, clone a drive to a RAID 1 of SSDs. I can take a clean install of Win 7 by plugging it's drive in and it will just crash but a fresh install works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744512%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) to remove your drivers and prepare Windows to be moved to another machine, that's a windows feature specially meant to avoid this kind of incident.

You should pick up OBBE experience and check the generalised option when you have to choose parameters.

Edit: Sysprep shouldn't keep showing the setup menu at every boot, but you need to complete it at least one time, it shouldn't annoy you then.

If the setup menu problem persists then remove your drivers manually from the computer manager, you can do this from the device manager in the computer manager, then moving your disk to your new computer and manually check for drivers from this same computer manager.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old drivers while still running on the old machine.

When deployed on your new machine, install the new drivers. This must be done on the new machine because many driver installers depend on detection of the hardware they are meant for, so that will fail otherwise.

It is important to delete the old drivers as they could conflict with the new drivers.

Also, do not move your driver folder over to the new system. Download the new drivers from the manufacturers website instead.

Comment: How do I install the new drivers when Windows fails to boot up to begin with? The only old drivers I have are the default installed from a Windows 7 that it installed.

Comment: Try to run windows startup recovery from an installation source. Maybe it can fix things for you. Also, from the link you posted I learnt that you will be prompted to install drivers during installation if no proper drivers for the boot device are found. Try inserting your chipset drivers in that stage, see if it helps any.

Comment: I've tried startup recoveries, not luck ;/

Comment: Move the disk back to the old machine, then boot windows and run sysprep to remove the old drives. Only after that move the HDD to the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep is only half the solution. Use sysprep, boot to WinPE and then copy an image using DISM to USB or LAN. Apply that image to new PC. Done and Done. Don't make this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: DISM? So use SysPrep to then image the drive to WinPE with DISM?

Comment: ImageX is deprecated. DISM is the tool that's used to make images now. Sysprep is run on the system and it pulls the drivers. You boot to WinPE and use DISM to build an image.